# Forwarding in PHP with additional parameters does not work

Tags: php, redirect, header

I have the following problem: as soon as I call up a file with additional parameters, the redirection does not work!
The forwarding is done with PHP **header**.
The file call in the browser:

```
https://www.mein_de_domain.de/archiv/Archiv-567KES.html,2021-01-04
```

The error message reads:

```
  Multiple Choices 
  The document name you requested
  (/archiv/Archiv-567KES.html,2021-01-04) could not be found on this
  server. However, we found documents with names similar to the one you
  requested. Available documents:
```

But the file is there!
Without parameter **2021-01-04**, the call works perfectly.

Here are the contents of the file **Archiv-567KES.html**:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: /archiv/Archiv-567KES.html" . ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ? '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : ''));
exit;
?>
```

Anyone have an idea why it works without parameters and not with parameters?

Comment: What is `,2021-01-04` in the URL ? Looks like it shouldn't be there.

Comment: _"Without parameter 2021-01-04, the call works perfectly."_ - what is that "parameter" supposed to represent? And how do you generate this URL? Or are you typing it into the browser by hand?

Comment: @webuser57, are you sure your web server can process a HTML file as a PHP file ? As typically, the PHP preprocessor is only invoked for .PHP file extensions

Comment: @BAerts most web servers can perform URL rewriting.

Comment: @AymDev yes - except if your rewrite depends on a PHP-script that can't execute because the PHP module isn't invoked as the file extension isn't recognised. See answer by Don R below

Answer (score 0):

The additional characters **,2021-01-04** are not being regarded as a query string, but as part of the resource name (file name). If there is no file named **Archiv-567KES.html,2021-01-04** that's why the web server can't find it.

Likely you mean the URL to be **https://www.mein_de_domain.de/archiv/Archiv-567KES.html?2021-01-04** ? The question mark character marks the beginning of a query string. You do seem to have the question mark placed correctly in the **header** call in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Is your webserver setup to use PHP when processing .html files?  As Don R indicated above, this is why I suspect your server is returning that error.

As far as how you're passing the parameters, all of that is irrelevant until you can get your server to interpret files with the .html extension with PHP.

Look in your `httpd.conf` you should see something that resembles the following:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

That configuration is telling the server to use PHP to interpret files that end in a `.php` extension.

Here's a [quick article](https://electrictoolbox.com/apache-parse-html-as-php/) on what I think will help you get this solution working. Again, I'm not familiar with your specific environment, but that's the gist of what I think you're looking to accomplish.

Once you have the server interpreting .html files with PHP, then you can focus on properly passing the query string parameters.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, thank you for all the replies to my post.

Well, I got the URL from our SEO department, exactly in this form.
Apparently, this URL came up in the evaluation of the data with the said message.

Regarding the parameter **,2021-01-04**:

```
https://www.mein_de_domain.de/archiv/Archiv-567KES.html,2021-01-04
```

I will ask my colleagues again and give you feedback here.